# Django set_language request working but not changing language

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, internationalization

I did `makemessages`, translated my strings that are `{% translate 'my_string' %}` in templates, and then `compilemessages`.

But `set_language` does not seem to be working.

My only translated language is `es`, `en` in the other hand is the native language of my project.

navbar.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="id_language" name="language" value="es" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info mx-1"><i class="fas fa-language"></i></button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    # ...
]
```

That's what I have. Then I put a `pdb.set_trace()` in one of my `middlewares` in order to check if the request is working as expected, and it does, when on debugger I type `request.POST` it has both the `csrf_token` and a `language` field with `'es'` value.

After response, the language is still set to `en` instead of `es`. What could be happening? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to include the "next" value yourself.  I whipped up a filter for use in templates:

```
'''
Tag to strip the language from a "request.get_full_path" in a template
so we can use the set_language view in templates.
'''
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def strip_language(value):
    '''
    We are just taking off the first (leftmost) item in the path if it is in]
    the language lists
    '''
    parts = value.strip("/").split("/")
    language = parts.pop(0)
    if language in [lang[0] for lang in settings.LANGUAGES]:
        return "/{}".format("/".join(parts))
    return value
```

REFERENCE: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28070